# Dealing with register_globals in PHP (On/Off)

Tags: php

Can anybody explain me simply with example what happens if register_globals in PHP is set to On or Off? I'll be highly glad. Thank you.

Comment: RTFM ? http://php.net/registerglobals and http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals It makes variables like `$_GET['foo']`, `$_POST['bar']` and `$_COOKIE['blah']` accessible as `$foo`, `$bar` and `$blah`. It was deprecated, mainly because of security issues that you get with bad coding styles. And now even is removed.

Comment: Just leave it off. Turn it off and walk away. Then google it, or search Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

In few php versions register_globals  is on by default.This setting tells whether or not to register the contents of the Environment, GET, POST, Cookie, Server variables as global variables. For example, if register_globals is on, the url

```
http://www.example.net/abc.php?id=3
```

will declare $id as a global variable. This feature is a security risk, and you should ensure that register_globals is Off for all scripts.

Answer (score 0):

**[Register Globals](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.registerglobals.php)** This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.

Comment: I was dealing with PHP 5. Thanks anyway buddy. :)

Comment: if you are dealing with **PHP 5** than why you want to use this. Just leave it.

Comment: I just wanted to know about it.